# How can I remove faux brick from a kitchen wall?

Tags: walls, kitchens, brick

My kitchen has these fake bricks placed over the drywall on the walls around the cabinets.

[image: bricks #1]
[image: bricks #2]

My question is, is there a way to remove just the bricks without completely tearing down the cabinets and drywall and starting from scratch?

Comment: How well are they attached? The better the finish the more likely you are to damage the wall etc.

Comment: They seem pretty well attached but I'm not sure how to tell for sure. I'm afraid to experiment much for fear of making things worse.  If they can't be removed without causing lots of damage, I may just paint over them or something.

Comment: I noticed an outlet on the wall below the cabinet.  You will need to investigate how (if) they extended the electrical boxes to accommodate the faux brick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove this fake brick without damaging the drywall under. You will have to replace the drywall, best solution, or do one hell of a good skim mud coat over the damaged drywall.  You can use a Rockwell Sonic Crafter or similar tool to cut the drywall cleanly at the edge of the cabinets. replace the drywall, mud it in, and paint.  There is no easy way in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to remove the brick with a brick chisel held at a slight angle and a hammer. You can remove any "mortar" left on the wall with a putty knife. Yes it will scar the drywall and you might get an occasional hole but using 40 minute drywall mud to skim coat the wallboard will make itall smooth again. Cutting out drywall can open a can of worms since you don't know what is behind it, and it costs extra. I just removed my own Z-brick in this manner with good results.